# Transform the double pendulum differential equations into a first order system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I have given a system of differential equations of order two which I want to solve numerically using a Runge-Kutta method. However, I don't know how to transform the system into a system of order one.

Here is the system of equations:

> $$\phi{_1}'' +g\sin{\phi_1} + \frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\frac{l_2}{l_1}\left(\cos(\phi{_1}-\phi{_2})\phi{_2}''+\sin(\phi{_1}-\phi{_2})(\phi{_2}')^2 \right)=0$$
>
> $$\phi{_2}'' +g\sin{\phi_2} + \frac{l_1}{l_2}\left(\cos{(\phi_1}-\phi_2)\phi{_1}''+\sin(\phi_1-\phi_2)(\phi{_1}')^2 \right)=0$$

Would appreciate help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $ω_1=ϕ_1'$, $ω_2=ϕ_2'$, $\mu=1+\frac{m_1}{m_2}$ and the coordinates of the linear system for the second derivatives
\begin{alignat}{6}
a_{11}&=\mu,\;&a_{12}&=\cos(ϕ_1−ϕ_2),\;&b_1&=\mu gl_1\sinϕ_1+l_2\sin(ϕ_1−ϕ_2)ω_2^2\\
a_{21}&=\cos(ϕ_1−ϕ_2),\;&a_{22}&=1,\;&b_2&=gl_2\sinϕ_2-l_1\sin(ϕ_1−ϕ_2)ω_1^2
\end{alignat}
and then use Cramers rule to compute the derivative vector
\begin{align}
ϕ_1'&=ω_1\\
ϕ_2'&=ω_2\\
ω_1'&=-\frac{1}{l_1}·\frac{b_1·a_{22}-b_2·a_{12}}{a_{11}·a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}}\\
ω_2'&=-\frac{1}{l_2}·\frac{a_{11}·b_2-a_{21}·b_1}{a_{11}·a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}}\\
\end{align}

---

<sub>(see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3931310/115115 for a complete derivation confirming the sign correction in $b_2$.)</sub>

Comment: I made a mistake int the second equation should be like this: $\frac{l_1}{l_2}$ instead of $\mu$ in $b_2$. Additionally, I think you forgot $a_{21}$ (You have $a_{12}$ twice)

Comment: Done. I also changed the linear system to be for $(l_1ω_1')$ and $(l_2ω_2')$ and moved the length division and sign change to the final formula.